# Random proababilty of rolling down to 1 from 1000

Tags: python, statistics

If I roll a random number between 1 and a 1000, then use this random number as the new range from 1 and new number for example if it rolled 500 the new range would be 1 to 500. What is the mean attempts to get down to 1?

Comment: This sounds like homework.  What have you tried?  This is really a problem that should be solved without writing code at all.

Comment: Its not homework, me and a mate were just trying to figure it out, I got the value 7.485965 and my mate got basically the same but +1 eg 8.48..... so we were just wondering who made the mistake

Comment: Also just out of interest, how would you solve this by hand and not code?

Comment: Is the range inclusive, i.e. are all rolls in [1, 2, ... 1000] possible?

Comment: Yeah so anywhere between 1-1000 inclusive but not floats eg 1,2,3...,1000

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you do it without code? I can do it with.

Comment: "Solve statistical problem without using code" is off-topic on SO. There could be other sites on SE network where it may be on-topic, but all of them require to show your attempt (possibly excluding SO's  python and android tagged questions).

Comment: Each round will, on average, cut the interval in half.  Thus, intuitively, you'd expect the answer to be log2(N).  The actual answer appears to be 5/6 of that.

Comment: I found `8.4886`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First 100 digits:

8.484470860550344912656518204333900176521679169708803665773626749957699349165202440959934437411845081

The exact fraction:

60484649691685213005704263395601539057400162783408267244512899237619438652990632145483065609746993406733894830753023779634909455921438397706516749459866848443713860300689848494770432824401693665503983189312845928714471628150308917599333411703457439105339322525040288258228358123705825959020674166771023657949375130672985808604458424810309577532641272807764258202248144159846532965261433911670727905231051075533636840438428488803438997
/
7128865274665093053166384155714272920668358861885893040452001991154324087581111499476444151913871586911717817019575256512980264067621009251465871004305131072686268143200196609974862745937188343705015434452523739745298963145674982128236956232823794011068809262317708861979540791247754558049326475737829923352751796735248042463638051137034331214781746850878453485678021888075373249921995672056932029099390891687487672697950931603520000

Came up with the same formula as Ben, but used the `fractions` module to get the exact result:

```
from fractions import Fraction

attempts = [None, 0]
for hi in range(2, 1001):
    attempts.append(Fraction(hi + sum(attempts[1:]), hi-1))

# Print the first 100 digits
a = attempts[-1]
print(a.numerator * 10**99 // a.denominator)

# Print the fraction
print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY@xbsMwDER3fcUBWSTHcaxkaQJ0zVh0DzwItRxrECVQzJCvd2Ug7lCO5LuHY37JnOj8kXlZJk4RE7sfCYkKQsyJBbf3Qikn4mOWgk/cvxL5Fv2gpsSYAwKBHT28PrWwfW/NVaHOFulczp5Gvcl0jexRnlFvxN1eB9NW1cEao9QO3xxIILPHFLjIasUYHkGKcrXBX@5gB5VXVruOntGzk1qpqXzTXC44HuG60VOKgdbLf/f23VthluUX)

Answer (score 4):

I get 8.48 for an answer. The logic is as follows: let `f(n)` denote the mean number of turns to get down to `1`. Then, `f` satisfies the following recurrence:

```
f(1) = 1
f(n) = 1/n + (n-1)/n * (1 + sum(f(i) for i in range(2, n+1)) / (n - 1))
```

For general `n`, there is `1/n` chance of getting `n` one this turn, and `(n-1)/n` chance of one after this turn. In the latter case, the expected number of turns is one plus a weighted average. Rearranging the terms gives the following formula:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def f(n):
  if n == 1:
    return 1
  return n / (n - 1) + 1 / (n - 1) * sum(f(i) for i in range(2, n))
```

You could also use `fractions` module to compute the answer exactly, although the resulting fraction is quite large.

---

After some fiddling, it seems that Mathematica can find a "closed form" solution in terms of [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) with

```
f[n_] := 1 + EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, n]
```

One way to derive this is to re-express the recurrence in terms of `y(n) = sum(f(k) for k in range(1, n))`. This also shows that `f(n)` is `O(log(n))` asymptotically.

Comment: Quite large indeed, doesn't even fit into a comment :-). But we can still use it like `numerator * 10**m // denominator` to get the first 1+m digits.

Answer (score 3):

The means satisfy the following recurrence: if f(n) denotes the mean number of steps to get to 1 from n, then f(1) = 0 and for n>1,

```
f(n) = 1 + (f(1) + ... + f(n-1) + f(n))/n -->
f(n) = n/(n-1) + [f(1) + ... + f(n-1)]/(n-1).
```

We can find f(1000) with the following script:

```
import numpy as np

means = [0]
for n in range(2,1001):
    means.append(n/(n-1)+np.average(means))
print(means[-1])
```

The result is 8.484470860550345.  I'm not sure if there is any nice closed form for f(n).

Comment: Actually 8.4844708605503449..., I'd round that up :-)

Comment: @Kelly I'll take your word for it; I guess there must have been a floating point cutoff happening. In any case, probably more digits than I should have copied and pasted

Comment: Yeah, I used `fractions.Fraction` to get exact results.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yet another handy tip, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The mean attempts to get “the number” down to one? So like E[len((1,1000), …, (1,1))]?

Possibly something like

```
from random import randint
from statistics import mean

i = 100

trials = list()
while len(trials) < i:
    value, attempts = 1000, 0
    while value != 1:
        value = randint(1, value)
        attempts += 1
    trials.append(attempts)
print(mean(trials))
```

which, as with many Monte-Carlo approaches, may require `i` be very large.

Comment: What's the result?

Comment: @KellyBundy not sure, responding on the mobile app

Comment: That doesn't prevent you from running it.

Comment: Installing an iOS interpreter, one sec

Comment: Wait, do you not know that there are sites like tio.run?

Comment: I’m a bad gateway :)

Comment: What I get for 30 trials is about 7.8667

Comment: As seen in Dan’s answer, the length of trials should be much larger for this particular solution…

Answer (score 1):

I found ~8.5 with this code:

```
import random

def f():
    i = 0
    n = 0
    r = 1000
    while n != 1:
        n = random.randint(1, r)
        i += 1
        r = n
    return i

N = 10000
l = [f() for _ in range(N)]
print(sum(l) / len(l))
```

Output:

```
8.5206
```

Comment: Down to zero? I don't understand :(

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question! My mistake

Answer (score 0):

we figured it out, I forgot to add a +1 to the number in my randrange in the while loop, I now get the value of 8.48....... with the code below, Thanks everyone who helped answer this question :).

```
import random
import math
random.seed(13)
import statistics

tries = []
for i in range(1000000):
  number = random.randrange(1, 1001)
  attempts = 1
  while number != 1:
    number = random.randrange(1, number+1)
    attempts += 1
  tries.append(attempts)

print(statistics.mean(tries))
```

Comment: You'd better start with `number = 1000` instead. And use `randint`.

Comment: @KellyBundy Does it make a difference? As randrange still gives integer values between 1 and 1000 and the number variable being equal to the random.randrange initially is why I set the attempts to 1 to start with, as it assumes the first roll has already been done.

Comment: Doesn't change the result, but it would be clearer, less code, and one could change the initial number to 1 and still get the correct result for that (i.e., 0 attempts).

Comment: @KellyBundy Ok thanks for the advice :)